# What is the "in which" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> In the end we shall make thoughtcrime literally impossible, because
>   there will be no words in which to express it.

I encountered that sentence while reading 1984 by George Orwell. What does the which refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically it refers to "words".

The relative clause "in which to express it" comes from a finite clause "we express thoughtcrime (it) in words.

Put together we have a description "words in which to express thoughtcrime", but we are told that these words won't exist "There will be no words in which to express it."

Comment: Oh, you are right. So obvious.